# Check if enum is in enum list c#

Tags: c#, enums

I have a public enum class called ScorecardTypes, Now i created a list from this with specific enums and i would like to have an if statement to check if the enum is in there:

Here is my enum list

```
public static List<ScorecardTypes> IsFsc()
    {

        var list =  new List<ScorecardTypes>() {
        ScorecardTypes.Generic_Revised_FSC_Specialised,
        ScorecardTypes.QSE_Revised_FSC,
        ScorecardTypes.Generic_Revised_FSC_Life_Offices,
        ScorecardTypes.Generic_Revised_FSC_Banks,
        ScorecardTypes.Generic_Revised_FSC_Short_Term_Insurers,
        ScorecardTypes.Generic_Revised_FSC_Other_Institutions,
        ScorecardTypes.Generic_Revised_FSC_Stock_Exchanges_And_Members
        };

        return list;
    }
```

and here is my If statement:

```
                if (Scorecard.ScorecardTypeEnum.Equals(EnumConstants.IsFsc()))
            { 
             if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SupplierTierName))
                {
                    throw new ImportValidationException("Supplier Tier is required.");
                }
            }
```

Which doesnt seem to be getting hit, but if i write it like this then it works:

```
 if (Scorecard.ScorecardTypeEnum == ScorecardTypes.Generic_Revised_FSC_Specialised) 
            { 
             if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SupplierTierName))
                {
                    throw new ImportValidationException("Supplier Tier is required.");
                }
            }
```

How do i write the If statement correctly with the enums?

Comment: Please could you put some effort into formatting the code in your post, and ideally rewrite it as a [mcve]? I'm finding it really hard to understand at the moment. It also doesn't help that we don't know the type of `Scorecard.ScorecardTypeEnum`.) (But fundamentally, `List<T>` doesn't override Equals, which is what you seem to be expecting.)

Comment: [`List.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1) is the one you're looking for.

Comment: You can't compare a value with a list of values. If you want to see whether a value appears in that list use `List.Contains`

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
if (Scorecard.ScorecardTypeEnum.Equals(EnumConstants.IsFsc())) ...
```

you compare a value of type `ScorecardTypes` with a value of type `List<ScorecardTypes>` for equality. Obviously, those two will never be equal: An apple will never be equal to a basket of apples.

What you *really* want is to check whether the list returned by `IsFsc` **contains** the concrete enum value, i.e.

```
if (EnumConstants.IsFsc().Contains(Scorecard.ScorecardTypeEnum)) ...
```